# How to get REST API RESPONSE in model in Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Below response parameter is showing in the controller but I want to get this response directly in model. Is there any way to do this?

I want to get `paidAmount` parameter directly in model.

**API RESPONSE PARAMETER**

```
Array
(
    [transactionKey] => 145000094
    [status] => 200
    [exchengeTxId] => 234kjh4h532h3234h
    [remainingAmount] => 1222
    [paidAmount] => 5
)
```

I want to set `[paidAmount]` parameter in `const FEE_AMOUNT` in model:

```
class Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee extends Varien_Object{ 

    const FEE_AMOUNT = 5;
    public static function getFee(){
        return self::FEE_AMOUNT;
    }
    public static function canApply($address){

        return true;
        }
    }
}
```